# How to calculate the counts of each distinct value in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a column filled with a bunch of states' initials as strings. My goal is to how the count of each state in such list.

For example: `(("TX":3),("NJ":2))` should be the output when there are two occurrences of `"TX"` and `"NJ"`.

I'm fairly new to pyspark so I'm stumped with this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know a thing about pyspark, but if your collection of strings is iterable, you can just pass it to a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which exists for the express purpose of counting distinct values.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I think you're looking to use the DataFrame idiom of [groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) and [count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count).

For example, given the following dataframe, one state per row:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('TX',), ('NJ',), ('TX',), ('CA',), ('NJ',)], ('state',))
df.show()
+-----+
|state|
+-----+
|   TX|
|   NJ|
|   TX|
|   CA|
|   NJ|
+-----+
```

The following yields:

```
df.groupBy('state').count().show()
+-----+-----+
|state|count|
+-----+-----+
|   TX|    2|
|   NJ|    2|
|   CA|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: how can I get a sorted list as the output?

Comment: add `.sort('state')` like `df.groupBy('state').count().sort('state').show()`

Comment: just to add to @Paul's comment, link to the api docs for orderBy/sort: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy (which also demonstrates how to specify ascending/descending order)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def value_counts(spark_df, colm, order=1, n=10):
    """
    Count top n values in the given column and show in the given order

    Parameters
    ----------
    spark_df : pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
        Data
    colm : string
        Name of the column to count values in
    order : int, default=1
        1: sort the column descending by value counts and keep nulls at top
        2: sort the column ascending by values
        3: sort the column descending by values
        4: do 2 and 3 (combine top n and bottom n after sorting the column by values ascending) 
    n : int, default=10
        Number of top values to display

    Returns
    ----------
    Value counts in pandas dataframe
    """

    if order==1 :
        return pd.DataFrame(spark_df.select(colm).groupBy(colm).count().orderBy(F.desc_nulls_first("count")).head(n),columns=["value","count"]) 
    if order==2 :
        return pd.DataFrame(spark_df.select(colm).groupBy(colm).count().orderBy(F.asc(colm)).head(n),columns=["value","count"]) 
    if order==3 :
        return pd.DataFrame(spark_df.select(colm).groupBy(colm).count().orderBy(F.desc(colm)).head(n),columns=["value","count"]) 
    if order==4 :
        return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(spark_df.select(colm).groupBy(colm).count().orderBy(F.asc(colm)).head(n),columns=["value","count"]),
                          pd.DataFrame(spark_df.select(colm).groupBy(colm).count().orderBy(F.desc(colm)).head(n),columns=["value","count"])])
```